# How to reconnect IB outlet

Tags: swift, iboutlet, sigabrt

I have been working on a new BMI App then I accidentally pressed delete on my calculate button so then I undid that and ran it and then when I pressed the calculate button it crashed and gave me error THREAD 1 SIGABRT so then I searched that error up which I've gotten before but forgot what it was because I have just started coding so anyways I searched it up and it said to delete outlets with errors so I deleted the calculate outlet because it was giving me a error and then I redid outlet and when I press calculate nothing happens now

Ive tried redoing outlet - deleting code redoing outlet then pasting code again

```
@IBOutlet var calculateBMI: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var inchesOutlet: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




func getHeightInInches(feet: Double, inches: Double) -> Double {
    print(feet);
    print(inches);
    let heightInInches = feet*12 + inches
    print( heightInInches);
    return heightInInches
}


    func calculateBMI(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

I Expect when I press calculate to calculate BMI using the code and connected outlet but nothing happens when I do

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Try Right-Clicking the button inside the storyboard. It will list all the connections made to the code. Make sure `Touch up inside` event is connected to the `calculateBMI`, but first make sure that method is marked with `@IBAction`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have an unused `IBOutlet` for calculate button.

Try this.

1. Go to your storyboard and click on the `viewController` that contains the `calculate` button.
2. In the right side properties tab click on the last option which looks like a `right side arrow inside a circle` its called the `connection inspector`
3. Check for any missing connections which will be indicated with a icon looking like an `exclamation mark (!)` where as all other connections will be like a `circle`
4. Click on the `X` or `close` icon for all the connections that show this `exclamation mark (!)` icon and then build and run.

Some images to help you.

[image]

[image]

Once you have cleared all the unused `Outlets`, make a new outlet for your `calculate` button and make sure you select the `TouchUpInside` option in the `Type` drop box when naming the `outlet` and make sure the connection type is `Action`.

Comment: Ok I redid the calculate action but before that none of the outlets had exclamation mark - I think it was because I redid outlet before but anyways I redid it as action anyways and ran it and when I pressed calculate nothing happened

Comment: Hmmm thats weird .... Try deleting the calculate button and adding a new one and then create a new `Outet` action. Also try to name the button action to something other than `calculateBMI` just incase that name is causing some conflicts.

Comment: Ok so I redid the outlet and it turns out it was my function it was in the wrong spot and was doing nothing

Comment: Yes you always need to make sure you are adding the outlet to the right class file which is connected to your viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this picture below with explanation

[image]